# Existe uma maneira de salvar tipos não listados no Settings.Default?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Em uma aplicação Windows Forms eu posso criar propriedades de configuração.

[image: types]

Entretanto não há o tipo `List<T>` ou `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Clicando em "Browse" e procurando na mscorelib > System.Collections.Generics eu vejo apenas o tipo `KeyNotFoundException`.

Existe alguma forma de estender essa configuração para suportar outros tipos? Como faço isso?

Comment: Uma possível solução seria serializar a lista/dicionário em algum formato que possa ser salvo como string. Talvez em json, ou meramente separar com virgulas (dependendo do seu `T`).

Comment: Que tal experimentar salvar em um arquivo externo. Especifíque o TKEY e o TVALUE que eu te amostro o código. Ok!?

Answer (score 6):

Você pode criar configurações utilizando tipos próprios (criados por você).

Para isso você deverá:

1) Definir através do atributo `System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs` como sua classe será serializada no arquivo de configurações;

2) Caso você opte no passo anterior por serializar em formato `String`, você poderá implementar um [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) para a sua classe. O `TypeConverter` se encarregará de fazer o "De/Para" da sua classe para o tipo `String`, neste caso;

Um exemplo completo disso tudo junto:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

public class Parametro
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Valor { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}={1}", this.Nome, this.Valor);
    }
}

[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.String)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ListaParametrosConverter))]
public class ListaParametros : List<Parametro>
{    
}

public class ListaParametrosConverter : TypeConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        if (destinationType == typeof(string)) {
            object listaParametros = (ListaParametros)value;

            foreach ( parametro in listaParametros) {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sb.ToString)) {
                    sb.Append(",");
                }
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", parametro.Nome, parametro.Valor);
            }

            return sb.ToString;
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {

        if (value is string) {
            ListaParametros listaParametrosRetorno = new ListaParametros();

            string strValue = (string)value;

            object paresNomesValores = strValue.Split(",");

            foreach ( parNomeValor in paresNomesValores) {
                object parametroDividido = parNomeValor.Split("=");
                string nomeParametro = parametroDividido(0);
                string valorParametro = parametroDividido(1);

                listaParametrosRetorno.Add(new Parametro {
                    Nome = nomeParametro,
                    Valor = valorParametro
                });
            }

            return listaParametrosRetorno;
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

}
```

Para este exemplo, estas configurações...

[image: Aba Settings Visual Studio]

...irão resultar nisto:

[image: Resultado durante a execução]

**(!) Detalhe:** A sua classe de configurações deverá estar em um assembly à parte. Por algum motivo a aba `Settings` do Visual Studio não reconhece tipos de configurações definidas no próprio projeto.

Answer (score 0):

**Se o TKEY e o TVALUE for *string* utilize o seguinte código:**

Exemplo: Dictionary configuracaoBase;

```
void SalvarConfiguracao(Dictionary configuracaoBase, string arquivo){
   BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(arquivo, FileMode.Create));
  Dictionary.Enumerator enum1 = configuracaoBase.GetEnumerator();
  while(enum1.MoveNext()){
     w.Write(enum1.Current.Key);
     w.Write(enum1.Current.Value);
  }
w.Close();
}
```

Bem espero ter te ajudado.

**A Lembrando o Dictionary pode ser usado com tipos de classes ou estruturas que tenham retorno. Então aconselho à você a criar sua própria estrutura e utiliza-lá em um Dictionary**.